# Django - separate apps on different uwsgi instances - share code between them

Tags: django, nginx, django-models, django-rest-framework, uwsgi

I have created a ReST API using django-rest-framework which my mobile application interacts with.

I would now like to create a front end web application which will NOT utilize the API (which uses class-based views and model serializers ), but instead take advantage of django templates to serve the content.

I am using nginx with uwsgi to run and serve my apps to the user.

To minimize the load traffic on the server I would like the API and web-app to run on separate uwsgi processes. I also would like to have different base URLs for the respective applications (e.g api.projectdomain.com / web.projectdomain.com)

However, I also would like to have both the api and web-app in the SAME django project in order for them both to access the same model classes and admin tools.

Is this something that can be achieved and if so, where do I begin?

If not, how else would you recommend me to do in order to achieve the code sharing/URL distinguishing that I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First things first: having django REST in your application doesn't obligate you to use it's serializers and views, you can mix it with normal django views and REST api views.

And yes, you can serve 2 separate web applications (that is not django apps) from one project. When you create new project using default template, django will create for you one serving (that is how I call them) app, with name of your project. You can create another one inside same project, add same apps in settings, configure it to use same database as main one, use different urlpatterns (and views) and serve it on another uwsgi process (or group of processes). There is only issue with having only one `manage.py`, but if both of your serving apps are using same database and same models, only urls and views differs, you can manage both apps at once, using only one `manage.py` for them.

Or you can just create separate settings and wsgi files, but in one serving app folder. It's totally up to you how you will arrange it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get back when I try this out!